# creating an installer for a java spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring, installation

any good tutorials on creating an installer that will install a spring mvc web application, namely setting up tomcat and postgresql on someones desktop?

Comment: Umm... isn't the idea of a Web application that no software other than the browser needs to be set up on someone's desktop?

Comment: But it is great for QA, Integrators, Implementors and even IT people at the client's site...

Comment: Target platform(s)? Should it also configure Tomcat and PostgreSQL as system services?

Answer (score 2):

Best thing is to create a directory containing all stuff (tomcat+ webapp, postgresql) and a cmd script firing up the DB and appserver. Zip this up. Than, you can use a tool like http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html to wrap it up in an MSI file, that unzips the application, installs Java (if necessary) and create shortcuts.
This is assuming the target platform is Windows. For other platforms you can use a similar approach.